# scons: *** [out/linux/x86_64/release/service/resource-container/librcs_container.so] Error 1

Tags: build, scons

While executing the scons I am getting the below issue. I added which are needed os.path.join(cborDir, 'src/cborparser_dup_string.c') file under Sconscript but still we are facing same issue.

> scons: *** [out/linux/x86_64/release/service/resource-container/librcs_container.so] Error 1
>
> scons: building terminated because of errors.

Comment: That message indicates the command scons kicked off came back with a failure. You'd have to provide more information to trace what's going on. This looks like it's from the IoTivity project, perhaps add iotivity tag to this question, it might reach more folks who are familiar.  Try running with `VERBOSE=1` on the command line.

Comment: If this is IoTivity, please add that tag as well.

Comment: iotivity tag is not there